# What is IKVM.Runtime, and why is it killing intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ikvm

I have a website sitting on a mapped network drive.  The 
`<%@ Page Language="C#"...` tag in the markup files are all underlined with blue.  The error I get is "could not load file or assembly 'IKVM.Runtime...." Beyond that Intellisense does not function for code inside <% %> blocks.  The intellisense for the normal markup still works.  Any idea's what I can do to get rid of the error and get back intellisense?

Comment: It also seems to have the effect that the code behind doesnt recognize mark up controls

Comment: I should mention the site uses the content management system Ektron (I don't recommend it, BTW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) is a way of running Java code on a .NET/Mono VM.

Quite why you're referencing it in your web site is really something you'd know more about than us. I suggest you back up the site, then find the reference and remove it. See if it now works - or if it breaks, you should end up with a good idea what was using it.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the reference in web.config files or maybe assemblies from bin folder depend on ikvm

Comment: There is no reference to "ikvm" in the web.config.  The bin folder contains too IKVM files.  IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll and IKVM.Runtime.dll